# by clicking add comment button it works for the first post only. how can i do this for all post in that wall

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

by clicking add comment button it works for the first post only. how can i do this for all post in that wall.
and also i stucked in geting post id to insert a comments in the table.

post.php

```
<body>
<h4>Welcome <?php echo $loguser['name'];?> </h4>
    <div class="postarea">
        <form method="POST">
        <textarea id="postcontent" name="postcontent" rows="4"></textarea><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="postsubmit"  id="postsubmit" value="post" />
                <?php $qry = mysql_query("select p.*,u.name from post as p JOIN user as u ON (p.userid=u.id)", $dbcon);
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){ ?>
                    <div >
                        <label style="color:blue;"><?php echo $row['name']; ?></label> <br />
                        <label><?php echo $row['post_txt']; ?></label><br /><br />
                        <input type="hidden" name="postid" id="postid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
                        <label>like</label><br /><br />
                        <label>comments  </label><input type="button" name="comment"  id="comment" value="Add comment" /><br /><br />
                        <textarea id="comment_txt" name="comment_txt" rows="3" style="display:none;"></textarea><br/>
                    </div>
            <?php   }
                ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () { 

        // $("#comment_txt").hide();

        $('#comment').click(function () {
           $("#comment_txt").show();
        });

});
</script>
```

Comment: The `id` attribute has to be unique within a form

Comment: If the `id="xx"` is not unique javascript will only see the last one

Comment: if i set unique `id`  means how i get that `id` in jquery @Riggsfolly

Comment: @RiggsFolly in fact it will catch only the first one to appear in the DOM Tree

Comment: @leo_ap Oh right thanks, I knew it was one or the other. Never needed to look to closely as once you know this you dont make this mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use classes instead of ids. Make the use of jQuery's `addClass` and `removeClass`.

You can do it like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  function hideAll() {
   $("textarea").addClass('hide');
    $("textarea").removeClass('show');
  }
  $('.comment_btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
   hideAll();
   $(this).siblings('textarea:first').addClass('show');
  });
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <form>
    <div class="comment_block">
      Lorem Ipsum Comment Text
      <br>
      <button class="comment_btn">
        Comment
      </button>
      <br>
      <textarea rows="8" class="hide"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="comment_block">
      Lorem Ipsum Comment Text
      <br>
      <button class="comment_btn">
        Comment
      </button>
      <br>
      <textarea rows="8" class="hide"></textarea>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons a class and bind the click event on the class

```
  <label>comments  </label><input type="button" name="comment"  class="comment" value="Add comment" /><br /><br />


$('.comment').click(function(){

});
```